# GCP Instance Template not showing VM using it

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-instance-template

I created an Instance Template in Compute Engine, and then created a VM Instance from it.

However, after deployment of the VM is complete, the `In use by` column of the Instance Template is empty, and not showing the VM Instance that was created.

In addition, when going to the newly created instance, the `Instance template` shows `None`.

Why is that? How can I see which instances are using the template?

Comment: Make sure you are checking the Instance template in the same project and region where you created the VM instance. Please note that labels defined within an instance template are applied to all instances that are created from that instance template. The labels do not apply to the instance template itself. Refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates) let me know if this helps.

Comment: I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided resolution has helped you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further.

Answer (score 0):

Instance templates define the machine type, boot disk image or container image, labels, startup script, and other instance properties.

Please note that labels defined within an instance template are applied to all instances that are created from that instance template. The labels do not apply to the instance template itself.

You can define labels by running [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instance-templates/create) or in the console while creating template click on MANAGE TAGS AND LABELS and then add a label.

Now create a VM by using a gcloud command or using a console. Once the VM is created under the basic information of VM in the console you can see the label defined for the template.

For more information refer to the [Instance Templates](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/create-instance-templates) document.

Comment: I'm not sure if it answers my question. I didn't ask about labels, but about the use of Instance Templates, and why I don't see the source template in the instance.

Comment: Once you define the labels while creating an instance template then you can see the source template in the instance. The labels do not apply to the instance template itself. Can you try once. Let me know if that helps.